# Message passing from an internal extension page to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, message-passing

I'm developing a simple extension for word translating.

What I'm stuck with is I'm using an internal page for settings. What I want to do is passing an array (or any data at least -i'm that devastated-) from this internal page to content script.

I've tried

**content script**

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window)
        return;

    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
        window.alert("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
        port.postMessage(event.data.text);
    }
}, false);
```

**internal page's javascript**

`window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");`

Internal page is a html file. I want to use it as a settings page. Like AdBlock's "options" page which you can reach from its popup page.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Jun",
    "description": "See selected words' equivalent.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Click Here!",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "css": ["/lib/jquery-ui.min.css"],
        "js": ["/lib/jquery-3.1.1.js", "/lib/jquery-ui.min.js", "/lib/jquery.mark.js", "content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }]
}
```

and some other useless things so far.

**For clarification; extension page link**

chrome-extension://inbhgljjpkpodbamjfkehcmloabbhccn/category_settings/categorySettings.html

I hope I could express myself.

Thanks in advance!

PS: You can see project from https://github.com/MisketAdam/Jun

PS2:

**extension directory**

```
.
|──*etc*
|──content.js
|──category_settings/
|  |──categorySettings.js
|  |──categorySettings.css
|  |──categorySettings.html
|  |──*etc*
```

**SOLVED**

Yeah so... After reading https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging throughly and trying out

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

at the internal page's javascript and handling it from background page got it working.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You should take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Is not `window.addEventListener` or `window.postMessage` is `port.onMessage.addListener` and `port.postMessage`

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: In addtion, what you you mean by "internal page's javascript"? Is that a web page's HTML, or an HTML file contained in your extension?  This question should be inherently answered by providing a complete [mcve].